# Is there any graphical display tool for diff output?

Tags: diff

I would like to post-process diff output and then pass the results to a graphical viewer, such as kdiff3 or xxdiff. If possible, I would like to be able to highlight in-line differences using different colors.

Comment: I don't think I fully understand what you're trying to do but I occasionally use a tool called [meld](http://meldmerge.org/) when I want a little more visual flair to my diffs.

Comment: linux or windows?

Answer (score 4):

If you can use windows, there is a great program that does this called [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/)

Here is an example:

[image: Highlight Line Diff]

Comment: +1 I love this software. But since the OP is using diff he's probably on linux.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this is not what you're looking for exactly, but you can do this in using vim:

```
vimdiff file1 file2 file3
```

Comment: a command line solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8800578/how-to-colorize-diff-on-the-command-line

Answer (score 0):

For highlighting, try [colordiff](https://github.com/kimmel/colordiff) or [highlight, with the `--syntax=diff` argument](http://www.andre-simon.de/doku/highlight/highlight.html); however, you don't need those with a graphical diff viewer as those have their own highlighters, so you should be able to just use a graphical diff viewer normally. The aforementioned [meld][http://meldmerge.org/] is one such tool, and you apparently already know about kdiff3.

If you're diffing non-files (e.g. `<(command args...)` subshell FIFOs in bash), all you need to do is redirect the non-files' content into files and run the graphical tool on that.